# Why does this web-hosted python code result in a 500 internal error?

Tags: python, html, apache, openai-api

I'm trying to run a python script to interact with openai API on my website (I'm looking to embed completions within a web app I have).

At the moment - I'm simply trying to get the code to run without anything other than the .py script.

I have this code on a file called script.py in my hosted (apache server) website. I visit it by going to [www.nessify.co.uk/cgi-bin/script.py](http://www.nessify.co.uk/cgi-bin/script.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import os
import openai

openai.api_key = os.getenv("API_KEY")

response = openai.Completion.create(
  model="text-davinci-003",
  prompt="List 10 science fiction books:",
  temperature=0.5,
  max_tokens=200,
  top_p=1,
  frequency_penalty=0.52,
  presence_penalty=0.5,
  stop=["11."]
)


print("Content-type: text/html\n")
print("<html><body>")
print("<h1>Current Date and Time</h1>")
print("<p>", response,"</p>")
print("</body></html>")
```

I'm expecting a list of books to be outputed onto a webpage.

But - Get these errors in the console:

> GET https://www.nysite.uk/cgi-bin/script.py 500

and then

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received.

I can't see why it doesn't work.

I have run other python on the script.py file (that does simple maths) and it executes - so I know the server is running the script ok...

Comment: It's not worth guessing why the error might have happened -- there are any number of reasons why.  Do you have access to the webserver error logs, so you can see the actual error?

Comment: unfortunately not...

Comment: One workaround would be to put all the code before the print statements into a try/except block, and if an error happens, assign `response` to be the text of the error, so you can see the actual error on the page.

Comment: I found the error logs...

Comment: The error log says this: nessify.co.uk [Sun Jan 29 17:57:00 2023] [error] [client 40.77.167.52:0] AH01215: ImportError: No module named openai: /home/cluster-sites/5/n/nessify.co.uk/public_html/cgi-bin/script.py   - the module isn't there

Comment: How did you expect that module to be available?  It's a third-party module, it is not included as part of Python by default.  Someone (presumably a Nessify administrator) would have to install it.  Was it installed?

Answer (score 0):

sussed it thanks to a hint from @John Gordon.

error log says:

The error log says this: nessify.co.uk [Sun Jan 29 17:57:00 2023] [error] [client 40.77.167.52:0] AH01215: ImportError: No module named openai: /home/cluster-sites/5/n/nessify.co.uk/public_html/cgi-bin/script.py   - the module isn't there

The module isn't there...